# Are there any examples or best practice for encapsulating large open data sets into R packages?

Tags: releasing-data, uses-of-open-data, programming

I've recently been experimenting with UK government open data with R, and it seems like I could usefully wrap up some of my work into an R package.

I'd want the package to download the data either as an installation step or the first time the user wants to use it, rather than include it directly in the package.

Are there any examples of or guides for this kind of R package?

Comment: [Similar?](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/acs/index.html)

Comment: hi, word of caution: i think it's rare that a dataset needs its own package.  for examples of download automation scripts that require just one smartly-written script and a single `source_url` call from the user, see https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree

Comment: @AnthonyDamico I thought the same thing initially, but actually OP is looking to write a wrapper for an existing dataset, wherever it may be hosted or mirrored.

Comment: @JasonWilliams another option would be to wrap your data into a Data Package (http://frictionlessdata.io/data-packages/) to make it more generally usable for people working with other data analysis tools (e.g. Python pandas).  We have a new R library for working with Data Packages, and we're looking for feedback on it: https://github.com/frictionlessdata/datapackage-r